# Cannot use windows font in visual basic using wine?

Tags: wine

I just installed Visual Basic 6.0 in my ubuntu 10.10 using wine but it cannot view the windows font.. why?
Theres any way to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not running Windows.  The Windows fonts are protected by copyright so wine can not distribute them.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Microsoft Core Fonts here:
http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ttf-mscorefonts-install